# Fixing container CSS doesn't affect how the container behaves?

Tags: html, css

I am working on making some customizations to a GitHub pages personal website template theme. In this theme, there is a [Distill-Style layout](https://alshedivat.github.io/al-folio/blog/2021/distill/) for blog posts which includes a table of contents.

The blog page is generated using [this .liquid file](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/blob/d85635262c46620a7494b4fa3b9663a9d900491a/_layouts/distill.liquid#L1) (excerpted):

```
  <d-article>
    {% if page.toc %}
      <d-contents>
        <nav class="l-text figcaption">
          <h3>Contents</h3>
          {% for section in page.toc %}
            <div>
              <a href="#{{ section.name | slugify }}">{{ section.name }}</a>
            </div>
            {% if section.subsections %}
              <ul>
                {% for subsection in section.subsections %}
                  <li>
                    <a href="#{{ subsection.name | slugify }}">{{ subsection.name }}</a>
                  </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </nav>
      </d-contents>
    {% endif %}
    {{ content }}
  </d-article>
```

I am trying to get table of contents to stay fixed on the left side even as the user scrolls down the page. For very long blog posts it would be nice to be able to reference it on the side to switch sections. I am making edits to [this section of the distill.scss file](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/blob/d85635262c46620a7494b4fa3b9663a9d900491a/_sass/_distill.scss#L77):

```
d-contents {
align-self: start;
grid-column: 1 / 4;
grid-row: auto / span 4;
justify-self: end;
margin-top: 0em;
padding-left: 2em;
padding-right: 3em;
border-right: 1px solid var(--global-divider-color);
width: calc(max(70%, 300px));
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0em;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns:
  minmax(8px, 1fr) [toc] auto
  minmax(8px, 1fr) [toc-line] 1px
  minmax(32px, 2fr);
```

By adding `position: fixed`, but this doesn't seem to be working. When I do this, nothing really changes and the table of contents remains stuck at the top and goes out of view as you scroll down the page.

I have also tried using inspect element to try to get a sense of the structure that may be conflicting, but haven't really been able to figure out what might be causing the problem.

What I think might be the problem: I think there may be some issues with conflicting/overriding CSS styles (perhaps with the parent container `article`). I would have thought that making edits to the `d-contents` section would allow the table of contents to stay fixed in the window as you scroll down the page.

I am fairly new to CSS so any pointers, advice, or articles would be greatly appreciated for trying to get to the bottom of why this might not be behaving as expected here.

**EDIT:** the full [website template repo](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio) is here.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @paulie_D I believe rendering this would require the entire repo since it is building a webpage for a website. I have linked to the relevant code files directly via the links.

Comment: `d-contents` has quite low CSS specificity. If it's true that there may be conflicting styles, maybe you could try `!important`. If that still doesn't work, try checking the element from the web inspector to see if it has `position: fixed` or if it is in fact getting overridden by some other selector.

Comment: @Simone thank you for your reply - how would I tell if it is getting overwritten by another selector?

Comment: It's more useful to copy rendered HTML from the page you're viewing than copying template code. You can do that with Web Dev tools in any browser. You can also see the CSS applied to that particular element after you select it, so you can check if the position: fixed is being used or it's being overridden. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools

Answer (score 0):

Applying [`position: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) to an element within a grid layout can be tricky, as it removes the element from the normal document flow, potentially causing unexpected layout results.

You have:

```
[d-article]
  [d-contents]
    [nav]
      Contents
      [section links...]
```

When you attempt to apply `position: fixed;` to `d-contents`, you should make sure it is positioned relative to the viewport, which, again, is tricky since it is within a grid (`d-article`).

```css
d-contents {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--global-divider-color);
}
```

The `overflow-y: auto;` makes sure if the table of contents is longer than the viewport, it will be scrollable.

It is possible that other styles from the parent container or global styles could be interfering. Make sure there are no competing styles with higher specificity or `!important` declarations that might override your changes. Using the browser's developer tools can help you identify such conflicts.

I assume here that `d-contents` does not require dynamic width adjustment based on the viewport. If your design is responsive, you might need additional media queries to adjust the position and size of `d-contents` for different screen sizes.

To closely match your original structure with `d-article` and `d-contents` elements, I will use `div` elements with corresponding classes to represent them in the HTML. Since custom elements like `<d-article>` and `<d-contents>` would require additional steps to be properly styled and recognized in a plain HTML context without JavaScript or a framework that supports custom elements, using `div` with classes will help to simulate the structure effectively in a .

For the purpose of a demonstration using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/6309), I will assume that `d-article` serves as a grid container for `d-contents`, and will apply `position: fixed` to `d-contents` to attempt fixing it on the page.
Note, however, that custom elements like `d-article` and `d-contents` will not have any special behavior without CSS or JavaScript defining them, so for this example, they are treated like `div` elements:

```css
d-article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
d-contents {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px; 
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px; 
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.content {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<d-article>
  <d-contents>
<nav>
  <h3>Contents</h3>
  <a href="#section1">Section 1</a><br>
  <a href="#section2">Section 2</a><br>
  <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
</nav>
  </d-contents>
  <div class="content">
<div id="section1" style="height: 500px;">Section 1 Content</div>
<div id="section2" style="height: 500px;">Section 2 Content</div>
<div id="section3" style="height: 500px;">Section 3 Content</div>
  </div>
</d-article>
```

In this snippet, `d-article` is explicitly defined as a grid container to better illustrate the situation you described. However, since `d-contents` is fixed, it is taken out of the normal document flow and positioned relative to the viewport, not bound by the grid layout defined by `d-article`. That should mimic the desired behavior of having `d-contents` fixed on the page while allowing the rest of the content in `d-article` to scroll normally.